# Find $y$ as function of $t$: $9y'' - 48y' + 113y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

> Find $y$ as function of $t$: $9y'' - 48y' + 113y = 0$, $\ y(5) = 4$, $\ y'(5) = 3$

My attempt:

> I found that: $y = e^{8t/3}(c1\cos(7t/3) + c2\sin(7t/3))$
> and its derivation. However when I tried to solve IVP, i stuck with a lot of trigonometric equations and i cannot simplify.

Can you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: since the initial condition is at $t=5$, it's going to be a lot easier to write the general solution as $y = e^{8(t-5)/3} (a_1 \cos(7(t-5)/3) + a_2 \sin(7(t-5)/3)$.

Comment: thank you sir i solved the problem!